# Trying to access array offset on value of type bool PHP 7.4.20

Tags: php

Getting notice:

> Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in
> uc_quote_uc_order() (line 311.

This only happens when login as administrator This is the code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_uc_order().
 */
function uc_quote_uc_order($op, $order, $arg2) {
  switch ($op) {
    case 'save':
      if (isset($order->quote['method'])) {
        db_merge('uc_order_quotes')
          ->key(array('order_id' => $order->order_id))
          ->fields(array(
            'method' => $order->quote['method'],
            'accessorials' => $order->quote['accessorials'],
            'rate' => $order->quote['rate'],
          ))
          ->execute();
      }
      break;

    case 'load':
      $quote = db_query("SELECT method, accessorials, rate FROM {uc_order_quotes} WHERE 
order_id = :id", array(':id' => $order->order_id))->fetchAssoc();
      $order->quote = $quote;
```

311>>   $order->quote['accessorials'] = strval($quote['accessorials']);
break;

```
    case 'delete':
      db_delete('uc_order_quotes')
        ->condition('order_id', $order->order_id)
        ->execute();
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Which line is line 311?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: This likely means that `$order->quote` has been set to false. I'm guessing `$order->quote` is the result of a database query and the query returned no records.
You should use getters and setters instead of accessing object properties directly.

Comment: Line 311 =       $order->quote['accessorials'] = strval($quote['accessorials']);

Comment: Okay, as @wetmarble has pointed out, `$quote` is `false`, because, as per https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Statement.php/function/Statement%3A%3AfetchAssoc/8.2.x `fetchAssoc` returns "An associative array, or FALSE if there is no next row.". So, you have to handle that case before trying to proceed, either work out why `uc_order_quotes` has no matching rows (hint: run the query manually) or bail if `fetchAssoc` returns `false`.

Comment: Oh, and if you can't make headway on the `uc_order_quotes` issue, maybe check https://drupal.stackexchange.com

Comment: Does anyone know how to code this to resolve this issue?

Comment: What is "this"? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Have you tried to run this using a debugger that could show you what `$quote` contains? Please don't guess or explain what it contains, debug it properly